# How to rewrite ext.sourcesDir in Kotling?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy

In build Gradle script we have the following:

ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"

Is it Groovy language?

What does "ext." mean?

How to rewrite these lines to Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `build.gradle`, you are using the Groovy DSL for Gradle.

`ext` refers to the [Extra Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties).

The above lines for the Kotlin DSL can be rewritten as:

```
val sourcesDir by extra { "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb" }
val classesDir by extra { "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb" }
```

Refer to [Gradle Kotlin DSL Primer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) for more details.